# How can I increase room for ggplot y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot is cutting off a portion of the y-axis when viewed and when saved as a jpeg. I am sure this is an easy fix, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any advice? Thanks

[image]

```
treat_freqplot<-ggplot(Treat_occur, aes(Trial, freq, fill = Treatment)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 1) +  
  #facet_grid(~Trial, scales = "free")+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, breaks=seq(0,100,1/10), expand=c(0,0)) +            
  labs(x = 'Trial', y = "Proportional Deer Use")  + 
  #scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Treatment",values=c("dark Green", "dark gray", "fire brick 4","dark blue"))+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=30, colour = "black",vjust=0.3),axis.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold")) +
  theme(legend.position = "right",legend.background = element_rect(color="black",linetype="solid", fill="gray100"),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm'),legend.text = element_text(size=25), legend.title=element_text(size=30)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black")) 
treat_freqplot

#ggsave('C:\\Projects\\CaptiveStudy\\Analysis\\Output2\\treatfreq_plot.jpeg',
       width = 20, height = 12, units = "in",treat_freqplot)
```

```
structure(list(Trial = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", "30%Shade", 
"60%Shade", "90%Shade"), class = "factor"), Use = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), n = c(2L, 7L, 5L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
45L, 9L, 3L), freq = c(0.037037037037037, 0.12962962962963, 0.0925925925925926, 
0.555555555555556, 0.0185185185185185, 0.037037037037037, 0.111111111111111, 
0.833333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    Trial = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
    "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", 
    "30%Shade", "60%Shade", "90%Shade"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Try setting `theme(plot.margin = margin(11, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5))`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you